# Laravel 5.3 Change users table default email and password cause an error reset password

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, reset

I have changed Users table email to `user_email` and password to `user_password`.
I am using laravel's default `make:auth`. Login function works fine but sending reset password email always check with email field and gives and error

[image]
here are the files

Routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    // Login Routes...
    Route::get('/','Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\LoginController@login');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\LoginController@logout');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset','Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
    Route::post('password/email','Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}','Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
    Route::post('password/reset','Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
});
```

Users model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\PasswordResetNotification;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

  use Notifiable;

    /**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */

protected $table = 'rdams_employee';

protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $hidden = [
        'user_password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    // Override required, otherwise existing Authentication system will not      match credentials

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->new_password;
    }

    public function getResetPassword()
    {
        return $this->new_password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */

    public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
    {
        return $this->user_email;
    }

    /**
     * Overriding the exiting sendPasswordResetNotification so that I can customize it
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new PasswordResetNotification($token));
    }
}
```

if i change `user_email` to email everything works fine. But need to use email as `user_email`

Thanks

Comment: How are you changing the column name in the database? Are you pushing a migration to update the rdams_employee columns?

Comment: Did you renamed column manually in users table?

Comment: i use rdams_employee table  with Users model. Not users table. rdams_employee have user_email and user_password.  there is no table as users

Comment: does anyone know the answer. still couldn't find out how to do